# adding data grid view rows to sql tables in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, dbnull

I am trying to add data grid view rows into sql table but [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSyRS.png) is showing although real data is saved:

> The parameterized query '(@Name1 nvarchar(4000),@Dad
>   nvarchar(4000),@Gender nvarchar(4000' expects the parameter '@Name1',
>   which was not supplied.

I did research a lot, some say to add dbNull value and nothing happened. I also read MSN documents but can't understand enough.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Member values('" & txt_fserial_no.Text & "',@Name1,@DOB,@Gender,@Dad,@Relation,@NRC,@Citizen,@Job,@Race,@Country,@Religion)"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
' Dim adapFam As New SqlDataAdapter'
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name1", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dad", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Job", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Race", SqlDbType.VarChar)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Religion", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Relation", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Citizen", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NRC", SqlDbType.VarChar)

For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid_preview.Rows.Count - 1
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dad", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Race", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relation", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Citizen", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRC", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value)

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'adapFam.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()'

Next
conn.Close()`][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Member(id,Name1,Dad,Gender,DOB,Job,Race,Country,Religion,Relation,Citizen,NRC) values(@id,@Name1,@DOB,@Gender,@Dad,@Relation,@NRC,@Citizen,@Job,@Race,@Country,@Religion)"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = conn

For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid_preview.Rows.Count - 1
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_fserial_no.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dad", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Race", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relation", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Citizen", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRC", datagrid_preview.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
```

Comment: Even though I parameterized the ID , the same error still occurred.

Comment: I have the problem, that the link above ("this error") is for some reason not opening. Maybe the proxy of our company blocks it. I can only imagine, that there is a problem with your primary key. On my machine, my posted code runs fine. Using MySQL 5.1.

Comment: thanks for your effort,@muffi, but I think it is not about PK as I gave MemberID to auto increment, AddressID is a foreign key.

Comment: I finally found the answer. It is at the loop "For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid_preview.Rows.Count - 1", it is somehow still working after all rows in grid views. Have to substract 2(-2).

Comment: -1 is ok. If the error occurs on the last row, then there is something wrong with the last row. I think you should loop until Rows.Count - 1 and check (every row), if the data in the DataRows are ok. Instead, you may lose data...!

Answer (score 0):

Defined datatable as global which is use for insert your gridview raw into SQL Server table and that same is user for binding your gridview.

Pass `dt` directly to your SQL Server stored procedure.

Create a function in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_xyz]
      @tblxyz xyzType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO xyz(Id, Name, Country)
          SELECT Id, Name, Country 
          FROM @tblxyz
END
```

This is code for VB:

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim cons As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xyz").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(cons)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert_xyz")
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblxyz", dt)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

Sorry for my bad English :) I tried my best to explain you. :)

Comment: thanks for your answers. But I am not familiar with "Using function in Sql and also I didn't bind my data gridview, I added from string array.

Comment: The data is saved into the database but that error still pop up, should I use another way?

Comment: if you are using string array then check string array has all required data? is you missing any parameter value? Some where you are missing values.

Comment: The error was at the loop, For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid_preview.Rows.Count - 1. Even all rows processed, it somehow loops again and it found nothing and so I substract (-2).